# How does Terraforming work in Eminent Domain?

Tags: eminent-domain

Terraforming says you attach it to a planet, and if it would be enough to satisfy the printed colonization cost, settle the planet. How does this work? Does this count colonization reductions from settled planets or Fertile Ground? If not can it only settle starter planets?

Answer (score 1):

The Terraforming action states:

> Add this card to a planet as 2 colonies. If that fulfills the printed Colonize cost, Settle that planet.
>   Note: Ignore Colonize discounts in your Empire.

As far as I understand, the following occurs:

Firstly, you can play it onto an unsettled planet to count as two colonies (much like playing a Colonize counts as one).

In addition, if once you've played it the planet has sufficient colonies to settle, you can settle it immediately (discarding the Terraforming and any other Colonizes and flipping the planet).

e.g. If you have an unsettled planet with a Colonize cost of 3 and one Colonize card already on it, you can play Terraforming to double-Colonize and then immediately settle that planet.

For Terraforming, all discounts are ignored, mostly for game-balance.

i.e. In the same example as above, if you had an unsettled planet with a Colonize cost of 3 and NO Colonize cards on it (but a discount to Colonize from, say, another planet) then you could double-Colonize, but you would NOT be able to immediately settle, since you do not reach the requirements while ignoring discounts. You COULD however settle it later without further Colonizes required, since the action remains on the planet and still counts as two colonies.

Comment: Hmm, I must have an older edition, my copy doesn't have the note.

Comment: Ah, you're quite right. It seems like there may not be a clarification on the card, but in this BGG thread (http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/708915/terraforming-questions), which is also where I got the description, the designer says: "In play testing I found that I did not like how Terraforming worked with that discount - too strong. Hence I decided on the restriction." So it may have been a late change, or only clarified in the rulebook somewhere (which I don't have in front of me to confirm).